# Binding a collection of geometries inside the Clip property (of a Canvas for instance) to an ObservableCollection in a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, binding

Consider the following example:

```
<Canvas >
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="100 100 100 100" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="150 100 500 500"  />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Canvas.Clip>     
        </Canvas>
```

I would like to be able to bind a collection of RectangleGeometries in CombinedGeometry.Geometry2 to a ObservableCollection in my ViewModel, so that I can dynamically 'punch holes' in the RectangleGeometry CombinedGeometry.Geometry1.

Since it is not possible to embed an itemscontrol into the 'Clip', I wonder if there is other way (maybe still using an itemscontrol in another fashion) to achieve my goal.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried binding Geometry2 to a GeometryGroup property?

Comment: @clemens not really sure what you mean by that. Could you give me an example?

Comment: `<CombinedGeometry Geometry2="{Binding Holes}" ...>`, where Holes is a view model property of type GeometryGroup.

Comment: Not sure how that would help. The collection i am binding to is basically a collection of squares. I need to bind each individual item in the collection to 1 CombinedGeometry in CombinedGeometry.Geometry2

Comment: You would obviously either declare an additional view model property that returns a GeometryGroup with a RectangleGeometry child for each of the squares, or alternatively write a Binding Converter that converts the list of squares into such a GeometryGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your view model has a `ObservableCollection<Rect> Holes` property for the holes in the clip geometry, you may add another property `HolesGeometry` that returns an appropriate Geometry, which is updated whenever the Holes property changes:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Holes.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HolesGeometry)));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Rect> Holes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Rect>();

    public Geometry HolesGeometry
    {
        get => new GeometryGroup
        {
            Children = new GeometryCollection(Holes.Select(r => new RectangleGeometry(r)))
        };
    }
}
```

You would bind to it like this:

```
<CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude" Geometry2="{Binding HolesGeometry}">
```